# Group by, array of arrays in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array as follows

```
    some_array = [["FANUC CORP", "100048", 9],
                  ["FANUC CORP", "100048", 26],
                  ["FANUC CORP", "100048", 23],
                  ["FANUC CORP", "100048", 111]]
```

And I want to group by in the following way:

`=> ["FANUC CORP", "100048", [9, 26,23,111]]`

Can anyone suggest something, any help will be appreciated

Comment: I think the reason you have received no upvotes is that all of the elements of `some_array` are the same except for their last (integer) values, so there is no grouping of elements. The examples given in the answers are better in that regard. (It is of course too late to change your example.)

Comment: I think also no attempt was made to find a solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use following

```
some_array.group_by{|a| [a[0], a[1]]}
          .map{|key, value| key + [value.map(&:last)]}
          .flatten(1)
```

For multiple values in group by

```
2.3.1 :046 > some_array = [["FANUC CORP", "100048", 9], ["FANUC CORP", "100048", 26]
   , ["FANUC CORP", "100048", 23], ["FANUC CORP", "100048", 111]
   , ["FANUC CORP", "100049", 19],["FANUC CORP", "100049", 126], 
     ["FANUC CORP", "100049", 123], ["FANUC CORP", "100049", 1111]]
 => [["FANUC CORP", "100048", 9], ["FANUC CORP", "100048", 26], 
    ["FANUC CORP", "100048", 23], ["FANUC CORP", "100048", 111], 
    ["FANUC CORP", "100049", 19], ["FANUC CORP", "100049", 126], 
    ["FANUC CORP", "100049", 123], ["FANUC CORP", "100049", 1111]] 

 2.3.1 :047 > some_array.group_by{|a| [a[0], a[1]]}
                        .map{|key, value| key + [value.map(&:last)]}
                        .flatten(1)
 => ["FANUC CORP", "100048", [9, 26, 23, 111], 
     "FANUC CORP", "100049", [19, 126, 123, 1111]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works perfect for me. I have accepted the answer aswell.

Comment: Welcome, glad it helps :)

Comment: Checkout `#flat_map`, cleans up a bit. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map

Comment: Though it is not clear from the question, I would expect the desired return value for your example would be `[["FANUC CORP", "100048", [9, 26, 23, 111]], ["FANUC CORP", "100049", [19, 126, 123, 1111]]]`.

Comment: I agree, in that case we don't need to use `flatten` i.e. `some_array.group_by{|a| [a[0], a[1]]}.map{|key, value| key + [value.map(&:last)]}`

Answer (score 0):

```
some_array.
  map(&:dup).
  group_by { |arr| arr.shift(2) }.
  map { |k, v| [k + [v.flatten]] }
#⇒ [[["FANUC CORP", "100048", [9, 26, 23, 111]]]]
```

Call `.first` if all the elements of the original array have the same first and second elements.

---

Or, for the exact case you posted, it’s even easier:

```
some_array.
  each_with_object(["FANUC CORP", "100048", []]) do |(_, _, v), acc|
    acc.last << v
  end
#⇒ ["FANUC CORP", "100048", [9, 26, 23, 111]]
```

Comment: adding `.pop.pop` will bring the expected result of him `p [[["FANUC CORP", "100048", [9, 26, 23, 111]]]].pop.pop`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a combination between @mudasobwa and @salil answers.

```
# backslashes so you can copy to console, remove them in a script

# mutates the original arrays
some_array.group_by { |a| a.shift(2) } \
          .flat_map { |k, v| k << v.flatten }

# doesn't mutate the original arrays
some_array.group_by { |a| a[0, 2] } \
          .flat_map { |k, v| k << v.map(&:last) }

#=> ["FANUC CORP", "100048", [9, 26, 23, 111]]
```

You could also change `a[0, 2]` with `a[0..1]`, whatever suits your taste best.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to obtain the desired return value.

```
arr = [
  [:a, "1", "c", 1],
  [:b, "2", "e", 4],
  [:a, "1", "c", 2], 
  [:b, "2", "e", 5],
  [:a, "1", "d", 3]
]
```

**Use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.**

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |(*all_but_last, last), h|
  h.update(all_but_last=>[last]) { |_k,o,n| o+n }
end.map { |k,v| [*k,v] }
  #=> [[:a, "1", "c", [1, 2]], [:b, "2", "e", [4, 5]], [:a, "1", "d", [3]]]
```

See the doc for `Hash#update` (aka `merge!`) for an explanation of the block's three variables, `_k`, `o` and `n`. (`_k` holds the value of the common key. That the first character of the variable name is an underscore signifies that it is not used in the block calculation. Often it would just be written `_`.)

Note that `map`'s receiver is the following.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |(*all_but_last, last), h|
  h.update(all_but_last=>[last]) { |_k,o,n| o+n }
end
  #=> {[:a, "1", "c"]=>[1, 2], [:b, "2", "e"]=>[4, 5], [:a, "1", "d"]=>[3]}
```

**Use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)**

Here it is helpful to use the splat operator to advantage.

```
arr.group_by { |*all_but_last,_| all_but_last }.
    map { |_,a| [*a.first[0..-2], a.map(&:last)] }
  #=> [[:a, "1", "c", [1, 2]], [:b, "2", "e", [4, 5]], [:a, "1", "d", [3]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `transpose` and `yield_self`:

```
some_array.transpose.yield_self { |*a, b| a.flatten.uniq << b }
 #=> ["FANUC CORP", "100048", [9, 26, 23, 111]]
```